# MS Word to PDF loses spaces

Tags: pdf, ms-word

I have a word file, which contains some code in a text box (written with courier) and nicely aligned on the right side of the code there are comments. Since this code came from real life, the alignment of the comments is via spaces. Like:

```
if (something == somethingElse)   /* Is something equal to something else? */
{                                 /* If yes */
     doSomething();               /* Then do something */
}                                 /* And we are done */
```

Now, I save this document as PDF, and it looks very good, comments are nicely aligned. However if I copy/paste from the PDF into a normal text editor (Notepad) the comments are not aligned anymore, seems the PDF has eaten all the spaces (and yes, in the Acrobat viewer I **cannot** see any space character, the comments just seem to be there after the line). This is what I get after pasting from the word:

```
if (something == somethingElse) /* Is something equal to something else? */
{ /* If yes */
doSomething(); /* Then do something */
} /* And we are done */
```

So the question: How do I save the file as PDF to have the spaces back?

Comment: Ca you supply the Word file in question?

Comment: There is no *obligation* to always save separate spaces as literal spaces. Presumably, Word chose to replace them with a simple "move" command. As it is a problem in Word, I guess it's OP for SO unless you are working for Microsoft...